# create a volume model from vtkImageData

Tags: 3d, mesh, vtk, voxel

How can I create and save a 3D volume model from a volume image vtkImageData?

Some people recommend vtkImageDataGeometryFilter, so I tried the following:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageDataGeometryFilter> imageDataGeometryFilter =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageDataGeometryFilter>::New();
imageDataGeometryFilter->SetInputData(imageData);
imageDataGeometryFilter->SetThresholdCells(true);
imageDataGeometryFilter->ThresholdValueOn();
imageDataGeometryFilter->SetThresholdValue(90);
imageDataGeometryFilter->Update();
```

Below is the visualization of `imageDataGeometryFilter->GetOutput()`:

[image: Generated vtkPolyData]

First of all the threshold doesn't work. 
Moreover, it doesn't output a volume model, but just some unconnected vertices.

Comment: Not sure to see what you want to do, as vtkImageData is a data model for 3D object. What do you want as output ?

Comment: @NicoVuaille as from my understanding, `vtkImageDataGeometryFilter` can convert the volume model into a mesh/polydata model. Currently, I only get the vertices with the same size as the vtkImageData.

Comment: indeed, 'vtkImageDataGeometryFilter is a filter that extracts geometry from a structured points dataset' (https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageDataGeometryFilter.html#details) and creates polydata. But depending on what you want to do it is a good thing or not. If you want to do volume rendering don't use it and see here : https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/VolumeRendering/SmartVolumeMapper/